# My paper was accepted by a Journal four years ago, but it has not been published yet. They didn't answer my last e-mail about it. What can I do?

Tags: publications, journals, ethics

It is a very important journal in the field. My paper is a letter explaining that an article previously published in that journal had a mistake, and that the correction reverts the result. The paper was accepted in September 2019. It seems that the editor does not like that my paper has evidence of a mistake in the journal. I considered complaining to the company that publishes the journal. Can anybody recommend an attorney to assist me, and maybe to legally defend me? I have been waiting for a long time now and they have the copyrights.

Comment: What's a usual backlog for this journal?  (I know a few journals that take more than 4 years from acceptance to publication.)

Comment: I would certainly go through your institution's legal resources before finding a random attorney for yourself. (Not that it's necessarily time to do that, just if you need to learn what your rights are)

Comment: Try calling and sending out registered letters. Document your attempts to correct the record. And yes, contact the parent company of the journal if you think that will help.

Comment: *WHO EXACTLY* have you been emailing about this? If it is only your editor, then send an email to the editor in chief. Or try contacting some other member of the editorial board before contacting the publisher. I very strongly suggest that you assume an honest error, rather than that the editor is trying to suppress your paper - that will not work in academia, and your editor knows it, and most editors (especially at "better" journals) are mature and well-respected people in their fields. Better to try other avenues before actions that might leave you looking bad.

Comment: Please be mindful of [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) before interpreting "my paper hasn't been published" as "someone's trying to hide the truth from the world", and *especially* before reacting with legal threats.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I can understand why reviews would take long. But in what situation does a waiting time of 4 years from acceptance to publication happen?  Is it typesetting? Is it such a rarified journal that they accept more papers than they are able to publish on their precious sheets? In any case, if it really takes 4 years, indeed the OP is best advised not to be confrontational.

Comment: @BryanKrause, your comment here would be the foundation of my answer. The OP may have a case to, at least, get their copyright back. But a university funded IP lawyer would be the best option IMO. Another issue is how copyright works for things not ever published, but that is a question for an IP lawyer. It could well be that by not publishing it, their IP has been stolen.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Either they greatly exceeded their budget or their staff quit.  In 2023 it's hard to hire clerical staff for cheap.

Comment: "It seems that the editor does not want that my paper put in evidence a mistake of the journal." This sounds like a very unlikely motivation. @CaptainEmacs In my case (just 2 years) it was a backlog of accepted papers waiting to be assigned to an issue. The paper was published online quite quickly though.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil If it's published online quickly, then there is nothing to worry about. If you can place it on arXiv, it may get the note: accepted for publication in XYZ. Maybe that's OP's best move.

Comment: I thank you all very much! I will write a kind  letter to the editor asking if there was a problem or a mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to me that the most probable explanation of this is that the editorial board member who made the 'accept' decision is unfamiliar with the system, hence the 'accept' decision did not actually go through (e.g. it should've reached the editor-in-chief, but it didn't). If the 'accept' decision reached the publisher, it would be extremely improbable that the publisher does not publish it.

So, make sure that everything is actually working as it should. Ask another member of the editorial board, perhaps the editor-in-chief, to check what's happening. You can also ask the publisher.

Note no response to email does not mean they're ignoring you - your email could've gone into the spam box, for example.

Comment: To amplify this answer: the aim is not to get the paper published. The aim is *to help the journal be a better journal* by publishing the paper. Whoever the OP approaches, if the aim is to work side by side to achieve this, it will almost certainly work better than face to face confrontation.

Comment: I thank you very much! I will write a kind  letter to the editor asking if there was a problem or a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Call the editor. Quit using email and call. Be polite and just ask to trace the submission. Nothing beats having direct communication and getting as many facts as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would send an email to the editor in chief of the journal or the publication team. Depending on the amount of back processing required, publication in a journal can take years, based on what I've read. However, you have to pose some, perhaps rhetorical, questions to yourself. Do you have documentation of your submission and approval? What is said by your colleagues, university, or supervisor? You also need to account for the actual time frame that takes from submission to publication. Publication involves numerous steps. The submission of the article comes first, followed by peer review and journal publication. In all academic fields, the average time from the moment you submit your manuscript until you receive a firm decision is one year. It takes an average of six months more after your article is accepted before it is published.It's important to use caution when wording your response to avoid coming across as conceited or biased.  It is highly recommended that you consider the possibility of an honest mistake instead of the editor attempting to censor your work. Keep thinking positive.

Comment: *In all academic fields, the average time from the moment you submit your manuscript until you receive a firm decision is one year. It takes an average of six months more after your article is accepted before it is published.* – That statement is wrong in this generality. There are fields and publishers where the average time to the final decision is a few months and the time to (online) publication from then is a month. Of course you can take a grand average over all of academia, but that information is barely relevant to anybody and nothing to base any advice on.

Comment: I thank you all very much! I will write a kind  letter to the editor asking if there was a problem or a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel uncomfortable to call, another approach would be sending a letter via the ordinary mail. Stop using E mail. Spam is very abundant now and some filters may be aggressive enough to drop your message without any obvious reason.

Staff change is a likely reason why some decisions have been forgotten. If they have changed they mind, should have notified you.

Never wait for as long as four years.